# 2D closed surface such that there's always a straight line to a point?

Tags: geometry, surfaces

AT work, we were wondering about exotic geometries, and we ended up to a question.

Can we make a 2D closed surface (in a 3D space, like a sphere) called S such that there exists a point on that surface, called O, such that for any other point P on S, there exist a "straight" line on S that goes from P to L?

I guess that such surface S will follow an equation (like `x² + y² + z² = 1`), but I don't really see how to formulate the condition of the straight line existence. I think that the "straight line on S from point P toward direction D" might be considered as the intersection of the surface S and the plane F that contains both the normal of S on P and the chosen direction D. But the calculus seems heavy.

So, is there such surface? Maybe in higher dimensions? What is the search field in mathematics that explores this kind of question?

Comment: I believe you're looking for geodesic manifolds which is a topic in differential geometry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic

Comment: This is a very special case of the Hopf-Rinow theorem, which implies that if $M$ is a compact connected Riemannian manifold then any two points in $M$ are connected by a geodesic. You can also prove this using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: @MoisheCohen & CyclotomicField Indeed. It sounds pretty simple actually once the night has passed... I guess we've messed up with some other variants (like "every geodesic of every P must pass through O", or "for every P, there is no geodesic that pass through O" so meaning it's a non-Riemannian manifold)